# Adjust two images contrast/brightness/luminosity/etc

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

What I'm trying to accomplish is :

- a user take a picture of an object
- I imbed another image in it

Both pictures were taken in different conditions.

Is there a way to "normalize" programmatically the image that I imbedded to match the contrast/brightness/luminosity/etc... of the picture taken by the user, so that it looks as realistic as possible ?

**Edit :**

Example :
photo 1 : A photo of someone taken in a living room
photo 2 : A photo of a dress taken in a studio (on a white background)

I would like the result to be the photo 2 looking like it was taken in the same conditions as the photo 1.

Comment: The meaning of "incrust" is ambiguous. You should provide samples images and explain what you are doing in more details. Otherwise my answer will be terse and probably inappropriate: histogram matching.

Comment: There is a normalize option in Imagemagick. Otherwise I would go with the comment by @YvesDaoust

Comment: what is mathematically normalized and matched does not necessarily make sense or look nice to humans. especially if you're dealing with colours. you cannot do this properly without very good image interpretation.

Comment: Depends upon the images you have. Two completely different images may not work well. But there are a number of ways to do it. One is to match histograms. Another is to match brightness/contrast (mean/std). I have two Unix bash shell scripts for ImageMagick that do those. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/histmatch/index.php and http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/matchimage/index.php. If on Windows, there are similar bat scripts at http://im.snibgo.com

Comment: A similar method for brightness/contrast matching can be found for python/opencv at http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/